# Passing a string array from JS to C# controller

Tags: javascript, c#, arrays, parameters

I have an array in JS ( `var selectedEmails = [];` )
After I collect the selected Emails from a grid, I call a GET to C# controller:

```
 $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '@Url.Action("SendEmailBatchs", "account")',
            data: { emails: selectedEmails },
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: (data) => {
                console.log("data", data);
            }
        })
```

When called, the parameter in C# gets no data. I've checked in JS, and the emails are in the array. Using breakpoints, I've confirmed the Controller's method is getting called:

Controller:

```
[HttpGet("sendemailbatchs")]
 public async Task<ActionResult> SendEmailBatchs(string[] emails)
        {
            ...
            foreach (ApplicationUser user in users)
            {
                await SendEmailConfirmation(user);
            }
            return Ok;
        }
```

Changing the data to `data: { emails: JSON.stringify(selectedEmails) },` will pass an array with 1 element only, containing a stringified list of emails `"[\"loes.vea@phanc.com\",\"MaAlonso.Mfizer.com\",\"cech@mll-int.cm\",\"jier.aris@si.com\"]"`

What would be the correct parameter from JS so that I get a string ARRAY where each email is an element of the array?

```
emails = [0]: "loes.vea@phanc.com\",
[1]: \"MaAlonso.Mfizer.com\", ...
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a gap between what you are expecting in the controller and what you are sending through ajax call.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> SendEmailBatchs(string[] emails)
```

Let's understand the parameter of the above function, you are expecting an array of strings and will refer to it as emails in the function body. So, you will have to pass an array of strings in the request body.

PFB my simple controller and corresponding ajax call:

```
[HttpGet("api/test")]
public ActionResult<int> RecieveData(string[] emails)
{
     return emails.Count();
}
```

Call from UI like this:

```
var settings = {
  "url": "https://localhost:5000/api/test",
  "method": "GET",
  "headers": {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  },
  "data": JSON.stringify([
    "john@example.com",
    "jane@example.com"
  ]),
};

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

Comment: thx, but same situation, when I stringify the array, without name, the "emails" param stays empty. if I name the "data" as emails : JSON.stringify([... then I just get ONE element in the array, a string like this : "[\"john@example.com\",\"jane@example.com\"]"

Comment: @rep_eoDom Have you tried moving "Content-Type" under headers as written in the answer?

Comment: here's the call now:
 var settings = {
            "url": '@Url.Action("SendEmailBatchs", "account")',
            "method": "GET",
            "headers": {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            "data": {
                emails: JSON.stringify([
                    "john@example.com",
                    "jane@example.com"
                ])
            },
        };

        $.ajax(sett...

still, I get ONE string with the text "[john..., jane...]" instead of an array with 2 items

Comment: @rep_eoDom Dude, Read my answer please, I have clearly written why this won't work. And it seems you have added a copy of mine as your own answer. Not the best gesture, But anyways, God bless you!

Answer (score 0):

so, after following [Devesh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18464383/devesh)'s suggestions I ended up with

```
var settings = {
    "url": '@Url.Action("SendEmailBatchs", "account")',
    "method": "GET",
    "headers": {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    "data": {
        emails: JSON.stringify(selectedEmails)},
    };
```

the issue persisted, because I needed to DESERIALIZE the result, in C#:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> SendEmailBatchs(string emails)
{
    var selectedEmails = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string[]>(emails);
    //DO STUFF
}
```

Thx